# pexpect - run script.sh over ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, pexpect, splunk

I'm having trouble programmatically running a local script over ssh.
I'm unsure if this is a problem with the shell variable substitution on the local host.

When manually running,

```
ssh monit@server1 'bash -s' < /u02/splunk/splunk/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/bin/cpu.sh
```

I get the expected output,

> CPU    pctUser    pctNice  pctSystem  pctIowait    pctIdle
>   all      11.21       0.00       1.50       0.31      86.98
>   0         0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00     100.00
>   1         3.00       0.00       1.00       0.00      96.00
>   ....

but I get

> bash: /u02/splunk/splunk/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/bin/cpu.sh: No such file or directory

when running the following code,

```
splunk_bin_dir = '/u02/splunk/splunk/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/bin'
hostname = 'server1'
username = 'monit'
password = 'monit#_'


command = "/usr/bin/ssh %(username)s@%(hostname)s 'bash -s' < %(splunk_bin_dir)s/cpu.sh" % locals()
print command

ssh_new_conn = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'

p = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=360)
# Handles the 3 possible connection outcomes:
# a) Ssh to the remote host for the first time, triggering 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
# b) ask you for password
# c) No password is needed at all, because you already have the key.
i = p.expect([ssh_new_conn,'[pP]assword:',pexpect.EOF])
print ' Initial pexpect command output: ', i
if i == 0:
    # send 'yes'
    p.sendline('yes')
    i = p.expect(['[pP]assword:',pexpect.EOF])
    print 'sent yes. pexpect command output', i
    if i == 0:
        # send the password
        p.sendline(password)
        p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i == 1:
    # send the password
    p.sendline(password)
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i == 2:
    print "pexpect faced key or connection timeout"
    pass

print p.before
```

These are the printed outputs,

> /usr/bin/ssh monit@server1 'bash -s' < /u02/splunk/splunk/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/bin/cpu.sh
>   Initial pexpect command output:  1
>   bash: /u02/splunk/splunk/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_nix/bin/cpu.sh: No such file or directory

pexpect is bumping into the [pP]assword line so I guess the password is being correctly passed,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the note from pexpect manual:

> Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as
>   redirect, pipe, or wild cards (>, |, or *). This is a common mistake.
>   If you want to run a command and pipe it through another command then
>   you must also start a shell.

This is the working line

```
command = """/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/ssh  %(username)s@%(hostname)s 'bash -s' < %(splunk_bin_dir)s/cpu.sh" """ % locals()
```

Comment: Thank you SO much !
Didn't really know about this Pexpect 'feature'